# Adding a measure value from power bi in power automate template's mail body using dynamic content

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

Here I have set a trigger in power bi if value triggers above threshold then send alert email,then I have create a power automate flow and want to add a dynamic content of Power BI measure value in the email Body.But here i can only pass this 5 dynamic content of the tile value at which alert is set mention below.

[image]

So is there any way that I can pass the measure value of power bi in the E-mail body of the Power Automate Template

[image]

I had to add the measure value using the power automate inside power bi, and set the measure value inside the power automate flow email body but while running the flow showing this error:- **"Flow save failed with code 'InvalidTemplate' and message 'The template validation failed: 'The repetition action(s) 'Apply_to_each' referenced by 'inputs' in action 'Send_an_email' are not defined in the template.'.'."
**

[image]

Comment: What about the value in `Tile value`?

Comment: Yes we can use tile value dynamically but here i want to use the power bi measure Dynamically instead of tile value in the body of the mail format.